# FuelPHP Oil utility error: 'This is not a valid Fuel installation so Oil is a bit lost'

Tags: php, command-line-interface, fuelphp

I installed FuelPHP using the manual installation (regretting now, should have used Oil but knew no better back when I started). I'm now trying to create data models and migrations using the command line utility Oil but I'm receiving the following:

'This is not a valid Fuel installation so Oil is a bit lost.'

[image: error]

when I use any Oil command in the fuel folder of my project directory -

```
such as oil g model user userID:int forename:varchar[50]
```

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong? When I create a sample project using the command line it seems to work fine. I have done a significant amount of work in the other project so wouldn't like to start from scratch!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed:

This is a message from the oil bash script, and you'll get this when there is no file called 'oil' in the current directory. The 'oil' script is in the root of your installation (it's a PHP file without extension), and you have to be in that directory to run oil.

Very stupid on my behalf! I'm a little obsessive compulsive disorder when it comes to cleaning my code and must have deleted it with the docs and install files by mistake!

Credit to [Harro Verton](http://fuelphp.com/forums/profile/4/Harro%20Verton) on the FuelPHP forums.